# Paginação Web com C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Eu estou construindo uma aplicação de administrativo, e nesta aplicação eu tenho uma página de mensagens. Estou trazendo atualmente as 20 últimas mensagens.

Eu já tenho a tela pronta para receber esta mensagens, mas meu problema é em fazer a lógica do botão que mostrar as próximas 20 mensagens, e assim consecutivamente.

```
//Mensagens Enviadas
        List<Mensagem> mensagens = this.mensagemServico.GetMany(l => l.LojaId == loja.LojaId && l.OrigemId != 0).OrderByDescending(l => l.DataEnvio).Take(20).ToList();
        mensagemModel.Mensagens = mensagens;

        return View(mensagemModel);
```

Basicamente esta é minha rotina: ela pega as últimas 20 mensagens ordenadas pela data, e de acordo com a origem (Origem do Cliente == 0)

O que eu gostaria de fazer é que quando eu clicasse em "Próximo" ele trouxesse as próximas 20.

Tive a idéia inicial de guardar em uma variável da *model* (eu tenho uma `MensagemModel` para retornar o valor para a *View*) a quantidade já trazida de Mensagens, ou pagina atual para poder ter este controle.

Sou iniciante então tenho duvidas de como passar algumas informações entre *Views*, como por exemplo, *Models*, e de como deve ser feito uma paginação.

Se alguém puder me da uma ajuda, nem que seja sobre a lógica que deve ser seguida para fazer essa paginação, desculpe fazer este tipo de pergunta mas não quero que esta paginação fique ruim então queria uma ajuda de vocês, obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma outra boa opção é o uso de um dos dois componentes abaixo:

- [PagedList.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/), aparentemente descontinuado, [com suporte a `async` neste outro pacote](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.EntityFramework/);
- [X.PagedList.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/X.PagedList.Mvc/), continuação natural do PagedList, mas suportando Portable, [com suporte a `async` neste outro pacote](https://www.nuget.org/packages/X.PagedList.EntityFramework/).

Uso:

```
// Suponha int? pagina = null como argumento da Action.
var paginaNaoNula = pagina ?? 1;
List<Mensagem> mensagens = this.mensagemServico.GetMany(l => l.LojaId == loja.LojaId && l.OrigemId != 0).OrderByDescending(l => l.DataEnvio).ToPagedList(paginaNaoNula, 20);
mensagemModel.Mensagens = mensagens;

return View(mensagemModel);
```

Comment: Legal sua resposta, vou conferir este método também, muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: o X.PagedList.Mvc é melhor que o Skip?

Comment: Sim, tanto que possui controles também para a *View*.

Comment: +1, não sabia dessa.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que usar mais método o [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
//Mensagens Enviadas
List<Mensagem> mensagens = this.mensagemServico.GetMany(l => l.LojaId == loja.LojaId && l.OrigemId != 0).OrderByDescending(l => l.DataEnvio)
.Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * pageNumber)
.Take(20).ToList();

mensagemModel.Mensagens = mensagens;

return View(mensagemModel);
```

O exemplo de código a seguir demonstra como usar Skip para ignorar um número especificado de elementos em uma matriz classificada e retorna os elementos restantes.

```
int[] grades = { 59, 82, 70, 56, 92, 98, 85 };

IEnumerable<int> lowerGrades =
    grades.OrderByDescending(g => g).Skip(3);

Console.WriteLine("All grades except the top three are:");
foreach (int grade in lowerGrades)
{
    Console.WriteLine(grade);
}

/*
 This code produces the following output:

 All grades except the top three are:
 82
 70
 59
 56
*/
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, já consegui visualiza como vai ser o funcionamento, só tenho mais uma duvida mas é em relação ao layout  , quando clicar no botão eu queria alterar apenas meu "messagebox" com minhas mensagem, acho que essa pergunta pode ser muito abrangente, mas o que quero saber e como você acha que seria a melhor maneira de se faze este procedimento, e quais ferramentas necessárias. De qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda, foi realmente util sua resposta.

Comment: William seria legal você abrir outra pergunta para isso